# MS Access VBA issue

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters, append

I'm making a report in MS Access - what I'm trying to do here is basically APPEND a query to a table that I've already created - I select the first value, change it and update the table. The issue that I'm coming across is - this report will be used by a VB6 application. So the user won't be seeing Access at all.

The thing with my append query is that it needs a `USER ID` to run (4 digit number). Normally when I run a report in Access I pass the parameters to a form in Access - and I use them to run queries. However, in this case, I need the user to enter a value when appending the query, additionally, when appending a query in VBA it first says `"You are about to append a query, are you sure"` (or something along those lines), so is there a way to automate that as well, so when I append it nothing happens?

Here is my code for appending and selecting date from the `tempTable`:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE from [tempCompanyMgmt-NOW];"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryCompanyMgmt-SUE" - i made this append!
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from [tempCompanyMgmt-NOW]", , dbOpenDynamic)
```

So as long as I press OK, YES when I get notified of the APPEND process and enter the parameter for `USER ID` - everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo in your markdown, should the 2nd line be:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryCompanyMgmt-SUE - i made this append!"
```

You'll need to remove the reference to the form inside the `qryCompanyMgmt-SUE - i made this append!` query, and swap it for a parameter name. You can use the Access interface to explicitly add a parameters clause to the query, and then using ADO (or DAO) from VB6, set a parameter value before you open/execute the query.

The `"You are about to append a query, are you sure"` message is an Access feature (and it can be disabled), so if you want the VB6 application to provide such a warning, then you'll need to create it yourself with a `MsgBox`.

Comment: It's not supposed to say "I MADE THIS APPEND"

Answer (score 0):

One option would by putting your append query into the code and filling in the parameter that way.

I don't know your exact scenario, but something like:

```
If not isValidUserID(me.UserID) Then
    msgbox "Please enter a a valid user id"
    exit sub
End If



Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "DELETE * from [tempCompanyMgmt-NOW];"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError


strSQL = "INSERT INTO tempCompanyMgmt-NOW ( FieldName1, FieldName2, FieldName3 ) " & _
        "SELECT FieldName1, FieldName2, FieldName3 FROM tempCompanyMgmt WHERE UseriD=" & Me.UserID

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

To validate the user id you could do something like:

```
If (Len(me.UserID) = 4 And IsNumeric(me.UserID)) Then
```

or

```
Public Function isValidUserID(varUserID As Variant) As Boolean
Dim blnRet As Boolean

If Len(varUserID) = 4 And IsNumeric(varUserID) Then
    blnRet = True
End If

isValidUserID = blnRet
End Function
```

Comment: That looks like a SQL injection attack waiting to happen. Building SQL with user inputted strings is a BAD idea. Access is sandboxed, but it's still not good practise, because you can end up with inconsistent data. Imagine if strEmpName was "' OR Is Null OR Like '*"

Comment: I edited to more accurately reflect the user id scenario.  There is no issue with an SQL injection attack since only 4 digit numeric data will be accepted.

Comment: I don't need to validate it. I need to reference the form in Access where the value is being passed it initially. I'm passing it to frmInfo userID

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the MsgBox telling me I'm about to append a query i included this in my module before I open my append query..

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
```

And I realized once I have the value passed to the form (userID), that value gets passed on as a parameter when my query gets appended. So it's all set. Thanks for all help!